# Print if origin in tuple is [0] (python)

Tags: python, python-3.x

I would like to format my code so that it would print the the the word `river` and `sand` if `value[0]` is called.

#### datafile.txt

```
river, 4
-5, 6
-6, 8
6, 9

sand, 10
6, 7
-6, 76
-75, 75
```

#### my code

```
textFile =open("datafile.txt", "r")
dataString = textFile.read()

value=[]
for split in dataString.split('\n\n'):
    split = ','.join(split.split('\n'))
    split = ''.join(split.split(' '))
    split = split.split(',')
    for x in range(0, len(split)-1):
        if (x == 0):
            value.append(split[x])
            value.append((0, split[x+1]))
        else:
            tempTuple=(split[x], split[x+1])
            value.append(tempTuple)
print(value[0])
dataFile.close()
```

The above code prints something like `"river", (0,4),(-5,6),(-6,8),(6,9), "sand", (0,10), (6,7),(-6,76),(-75,75)`. I would like it it print river and sand when value[0] is called. How would I change my code to do that? The data comes from a text file.

The expected output when `value[0]` is called should only print `"river"` and `"sand"` while all others are ignored and when `value[1:]` is called everything else prints except the values of `"sand"` and `"river"`.

Also values of `value[0]` should be checked:

```
label = value[0]
if (label=='river'):
  print("river")
elif (label=='sand')
  print("sand")
```

Comment: _"The above code prints something like..."_ It does? I don't see a `print` function anywhere. Is this your whole code? Also, what do you mean by "when value[0] is called"? like, `value[0]()`?

Comment: I assume that the text at the top was supposed to be the contents of `datafile.txt`.

Comment: Please do not create a variable called `split`. Especially if it is storing the result of a `join()`... Name your variables more intelligently. Self-documentation is the key to successful coding.

Comment: @TomFenech, yes that's right

Comment: Can you edit your question, explicitly stating the expected output?

Comment: Like @Kevin, I do not understand your question. Neither how you "call" the first value of a list (which may or may not be callable), nor why you need to test if something is called in a condition in simple code like this with no imports. Why else would it be called unless you explicitly called it?

Comment: How does `value[0]` contain `"river"` **and** `"sand"`? The code you have posted suggests that it should only contain `"river"` **or** `"sand"`. Either way, it is redundant, as you could just do `print(value[0])` instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that this does what you want:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

textFile =open("datafile.txt", "r")

# construct list of non-empty lines
# strip trailing newline and split on ','
lines = [l for l in (m.rstrip('\n').split(',') 
                     for m in textFile.readlines()) if len(l) > 1]

# make tuple from names
names = tuple(a for a,b in lines if a.isalpha())

# prepend names to list of tuples built from each line
# alphabetical entries are substituted for 0s
value = [names] + [(0,b) if a.isalpha() else (a,b) for a,b in lines]

print value
```

---

**edit**: I think that this approach is a little cleaner:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

# use "with" to avoid having to close the file
with open("datafile.txt") as textFile:
    # get array containing all values in the file
    v = textFile.read().replace(',','').split()
    # extract the names into a separate tuple
    names = [tuple(filter(str.isalpha, v))]
    # make tuples out of each pair of values, replacing names with zeroes
    values = [(0,b) if a.isalpha() else (a,b) for a,b in zip(v[::2], v[1::2])]
    # concatenate the two
    values = names + values

print values
```

output:

```
[('river', 'sand'), (0, ' 4'), ('-5', ' 6'), ('-6', ' 8'), ('6', ' 9'), (0, ' 10'), ('6', ' 7'), ('-6', ' 76'), ('-75', ' 75')]
```

Comment: Your code is working but there is one tiny thing; when i try to check `label=value[0] if (label== 'sand'): print("sand") elif (label == 'river'): print("river")` its not working

Comment: @nyabuto That's because `value[0]` isn't a `string`, it's a `tuple` containing two strings. I thought that's what you wanted. It's very difficult to tell what the structure of your expected output is. I suggest you edit your question to make it clearer exactly what you want.

Comment: I have edited the question as clear as I think its understandable to what output i am looking for

Answer (score 1):

Like others, I don't completely understand the request, but here's my take:

```
value = zip(*[stanza.split(',') for stanza in dataString.split('\n\n')])
```

This causes `value[0]` to print "*the string "river" and "sand"*", while `value[1:]` prints "*everything else*".

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand your question, but I think this might do what you want:

```
textFile =open("datafile.txt", "r")
dataString = textFile.read()

res =  dataString.replace(',',' ').split()

value = [[i for i in res if i.isalpha()] , [i for i in res if not i.isalpha()]]
```

Comment: This works as expected but it prints `river4` instead of `0,4`

Comment: I had a typo in the code, please try again. it works fine for me.